# SMS from Android phone with different callback contact name

Tags: android, sms

I have developed an android application which now I want to extend so as it can send text messages.

Most probably I will be able to find documentation on how to send a text message, but what I am looking for is something I don't know how to do a research on it.

There are two types of text messages you can receive.

One type is from a contact you already know, hence you will see the contact name.

Second type is from a contact you don't know. And, depending on the contact, you will either see a mobile number or a name (eg Google).

My goal is to extend my android application to send a text message in a way that the recipient will see a name as sender (eg Google) and not a mobile number.

I cannot extend my application to use 3G to communicate with a server and send the sms through the server nor I can use an online service which is going to send the sms.

I have to either send the text message from the android application directly or send an sms to an sms service to forward the text message to the recipient.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: sendTextMessage() method in smsManager class take 5 arguments (i.e destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent) and destinationaddress is always number ( due to its uniqueness ) not name. And on the receiver end destinationaddress is comapare with contact list if a name is available against the destinationaddress  then its shows name in place of number.

Comment: @Manoj Pal - thanks but his is how 'normal' sms works. I don't need that.